# Sparkle framework: Is it possible to create a backup of the previous version before updating?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sparkle

I'm using [Sparkle framework](https://sparkle-project.org) to implement automatic updates in a macOS app. If possible, I'd like for the previous version of the app to be backed up somewhere before an update is performed. Can such a thing be accomplished using Sparkle?

Answer (score 0):

The Sparkle updater has about a *billion* delegate messages that it sends; it wouldn't be hard to intercept one of them to first make a backup of your application package somewhere before allowing the update to proceed.

I'd start by looking for a critical point in the update like:

```
@protocol SUUpdaterDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)updater:(SUUpdater *)updater willDownloadUpdate:(SUAppcastItem *)item withRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
```